# Need to click only one layout out of 2 relative layouts which is in linear layout

Tags: android

Need to click only one layout out of 2 relative layouts, but when I click any - both gets selected. How can I select particular view?

Please find screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZMw1.png]

Java code

```
    final ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer,
            mDrawerList, false);
    mTxtAddLeague = (TextView) footer.findViewById(R.id.add_league);
    mTxtLogout = (TextView) footer.findViewById(R.id.logout);
    mDrawerList.addFooterView(footer, null, true);
    mTxtAddLeague.setOnClickListener(this);
    mTxtLogout.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Add League text click  
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.logout) {
       //
       }
       else if(v.getId() == R.id.add_league) {
        mTxtAddLeague.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
       }
   }
```

Here is my footer.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_item_height">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/view_height"
            android:background="@color/hints" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_child"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/drawer_left_parent_image"
            android:src="@drawable/editp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/add_league"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/drawer_left_parent_text"
            android:text="@string/add_league"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_item_height">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/view_height"
            android:background="@color/hints" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_child_second"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/drawer_left_parent_image"
            android:src="@drawable/editp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/drawer_left_parent_text"
            android:text="@string/logout"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I select particular view?

Comment: What is your first layout an what is second layout..Specify clearly

Comment: *select layout*? Or add layout in listview. Do you mean you want to add just 1 Relative Layout (from footer xml) in ListView?

Comment: There is no IMAGE, I am not able to get what you want

Comment: thanku sir for response  please sir check this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/sZMw1

Comment: Unable to open the link. Also the question is very unclear.

Comment: My first and second layout is in Footer.xml file looks like this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/sZMw1.png

Comment: Where have you added Logout?

Comment: My first and second layout is within one layout looks like above image  add league is my first layout and logout is second

Comment: Please add onclick listener as well in java code.

Comment: One more, can I see your onClickListener? or your implementation that contains it?

Comment: updated with onclicklistener